# How to create child element and move it inside parent?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create Tic-Tac-Toe game and the problem now is that I'm creating svg element when empty area is clicked, but don't know how to move it inside the parent (and how to make that child element). Need your help, thanks!

```
let clickableAreas = document.querySelectorAll('.clickable-area');
let step = true;

function clickArea(e) {
  if(step) {
    let img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = './images/cross.svg';
    step = false;
  }
  else {
    let img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = './images/circle.svg';
    step = true;
  }
  // testing class toggle
  e.classList.toggle("empty");
}

for(let i = 0; i < clickableAreas.length; i++) {
  document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    clickArea(event.target);
  });
}
```

Comment: `e.appendChild(img)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks good so far. You should be able to call [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) to add the image to the correct area.

```js
function clickArea(e) {
  let img = document.createElement('img');
  if(step) {
    img.src = './images/cross.svg';
    step = false;
  }
  else {
    img.src = './images/circle.svg';
    step = true;
  }
  // testing class toggle
  e.classList.toggle("empty");

  // Add the image to the DOM element
  e.appendChild(img);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an element with `element.appendChild(childElement)`. An example would be

```
const parent = document.getElementById('parent'); 

const img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = './images/circle.svg';

parent.appendChild(img);
```

Would result in the html looking like

```
<div id='parent'> 
  <img src="./images/circle.svg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Once your element is created you need (as you have mentioned) add it to another *node* which will become this new element parent. For that you can use [Node.appendChild(childNode)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) which does exactly that: appends `childNode` to `Node`

```js
function clickArea(e) {
  let parent = e // or get your parent element.
  if(step) {
    let img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = './images/cross.svg';
    step = false;
    parent.appendChild(img)
  }
  else {
    let img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = './images/circle.svg';
    step = true;
    parent.appendChild(img)
  }
  // testing class toggle
  e.classList.toggle("empty");
}
```

I would also recommend to extract the `img` creation outside the if so you can avoid duplicated code:

```js
function clickArea(e) {
  let parent = e // get your parent element.
  let img = document.createElement('img');
  if(step) {
    img.src = './images/cross.svg';
    step = false;
    parent.appendChild(img)
  }
  else {
    img.src = './images/circle.svg';
    step = true;
    parent.appendChild(img)
  }
  // testing class toggle
  e.classList.toggle("empty");
}
```